# GenemuFormBundle select2 minimal configuration

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, symfony, jquery-select2

The GenemuFormBundle comes with no js and css files. So do I have to download the corresponded files whenever I want to use one of its features.

Also, even when I add the css and js files for the select2 feature, no changes to select fields are happening.

However, when I add this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
         $("select").select2();

    });
```

The select2 fields appears but this can be done even without using the GenemuFormBundle and genemu_jqueryselect2_choice form type.

So my question is why this bundle is not working for me? and what does it really do?

Comment: do you have an example

Comment: I managed to get it select2 to work by adding this:

{% block stylesheets %}
    {{ form_stylesheet(form) }}
{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}
    {{ form_javascript(form) }}
{% endblock %}

However the AutoComplete still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Genemu is no longer maintained. The way I use it is just download the CSS and the JS from the official site and add class="select2" when I want to use it in a form and the autocomplete function does work.